# Sum row in Excel/Google Sheets based on Condition

Tags: excel, google-sheets

It seems like this question should exist somewhere, but I can't seem to find it...exactly.

The most similar solution I can find requires the use of `SUMIFS` or `SUMIF`, which only seems to add up numbers in a column, not spanning multiple columns. Here's an example sheet with 2 rows:

```
      A             B    C    D    E    F    G    H  ...
1     2015-01-01    0    1    6   12   45   12    5  ...
2     2016-01-01    256 43   13   35  134  135   12  ...
```

Now I'd like to have a cell somewhere that adds all of the cells in the row for `2015-01-01`. My attempt looks like:

`SUMIF(A1:A30,"2015-01-01", B1:BJ30)`

But this only yields the sum of the column B, so `0` for the exact formula above or `256` if I were to do this for the year `2016`.

When trying something with `SUMIFS`, I'm told that the criterion range's size should match the sum range size, which isn't the case because my criterion range is only the first column of dates.

How can I add all the values in a row if the first cell's date matches my criterion? It may be worthwhile to note that this is in Google Sheets, not Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both excel and googlesheets you can use a `SUMPRODUCT`, for example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A30 = DATE(2015, 1, 1)) * B1:BJ30)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try either of these:

```
=if(A1=date(2015,1,1),sum(B1:F1),"")

=if(A1=A1,sum(B1:F1),"")
```